# What is the relationship between number of perfect squares and number of perfect cubes?

Tags: square-numbers, perfect-powers

If S is the "number" of perfect squares between 1 and a specific integer N and Q is the "number" of perfect cubes between 1 to N. How we can show the relationship between S and Q?

Please explain with mathematical proof.

Answer (score 3):

You have

$$S = \lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor$$

Indeed, the square between 1 and N are :

$$1, 2^2, 3^2, \cdots, (S-1)^2, S^2$$

With $S$ an integer such that $\sqrt{N}-1 < S \leq \sqrt{N}$

Same idea with the cube :

$$Q =  \lfloor \sqrt[3]{N} \rfloor$$

Now, I'm not sure there is an explicit relation between the two. On average, $\frac{S}{Q} \sim N^{\frac{1}{6}}$

Comment: a (logged) plot for say up to 10^6 would be interesting

Comment: @MichaelChirico Agreed, I think this is my confusion. Let's say N is a perfect power of 6 then what will be the relationship between S and Q ?

Comment: [wolfram log plot](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+plot+floor%28sqrt%28x%29%29%2Ffloor%28cuberoot%28x%29%29+and+x%5E%281%2F6%29+for+x%3D0+to+e%5E6&x=0&y=0)

Comment: cool. so much fluctuation around $n^(1/6)$

Comment: @qasimzee at a perfect power of 6, Tryss' relationship holds exactly. Everywhere else, this is an approximation